# How to get dual graph with networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want a [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of the following planar graph g.

```
from networkx.generators.lattice import hexagonal_lattice_graph;
g = hexagonal_lattice_graph(2,3);
```

Does network x have a function to return the dual graph?
I don't even know the way to get faces of g.

Comment: Looking for a neat way to do it too. Looks as if at the time of writing one has to do it the hard way: (1) compute a combinatorial embedding with check_planarity() (2) the embedding allows one to get a the "right-hand" face of an edge so go over all edges and find the right-hand and left-hand side of each (3) call unique ----> you've got the list of faces. It's a lot of work but it's doable.

Comment: sage does have such a function: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.planar_dual But you'd need to install sage which also turns out to be not entirely trivial...